# Check if a localStorage variable exists then set an else if function

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to code this:

1. When page is run for the first time I need set a localStorage item,
2. then, on further runs, check if the item exists in localStorage,
3. if it exists do nothing,
4. else set the item to localStorage

:  Somewhere else in page this variable is modified and those changes must remain on any further page reload.

but I am very stuck on this.

This is my code so far:

```
function populateStorage() {
    var pictureSrc = [ new Logo({"picSrcl":"data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTMzIiBoZWlna........48L3N2Zz4K"}),];
    var lS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Logos"));
    if (lS === true) {
        // here is where I am failing not to overwrite Logos variable
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("Logos", JSON.stringify(pictureSrc));
    }
}
```

How can I acomplish the task of not overwriting the Logos variable if it already exits?

After Darryl Noakes's answer this is what I get on my localStorage:

[image: localStorage when empty]

Now if I set the item manually, then the code works perfectly:

[image: localStorage manually populated]

And after reload of the page:

[image: localSotorage after reload]

Later, after adding more stuff to localStorage and reload the page it still works:

[image: localStorage after adding some stuff and reloading the page]

It only fails on placing the item at first run.

After Darryl Noakes's comment on calling the function I just added `window.onload = populateStorage();` and now it works as expected creating the item at first load of the page. Then the final code looks like this:

```
function populateStorage() {
    var lS = localStorage.getItem("Logos");

    if (!lS) {
        var pictureSrc = JSON.stringify([
            new Logo({ "picSrcl": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTMzIiBoZWlna........48L3N2Zz4K" })
        ]);

        localStorage.setItem("Logos", pictureSrc);
    }
}

window.onload = populateStorage();
```

Comment: simply put the condition ```if(lS)``` it will return true if having a value and false if there is no value

Comment: Just for clarity, please use "`localStorage` item" or "storage item" instead of "variable", in the places where you are referring to the data stored in `localStorage`.

Comment: Where are you calling `populateStorage`?

Comment: Oh, I forgot that! Should I do it? How as there is no button or any other function to trigger this one. How would it be called then?

Comment: Issue fixed. I added `window.onload = populateStorage();` outside at the end of the function and it creates the item at first load, just as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you compare `lS` with `true`. As `lS` is an array if it is present in `localStorage` and `null` if it is not (as `localStorage.getItem()` returns `null` for non-existent items and `JSON.parse()` parses `null` as `null`), **this will *always* be false. Instead, you can check if it is `null` or not.**

Also, as you are just checking if the item is present, you don't actually need to parse it, either; you can simply check whether the value returned by `localStorage.getItem()` is `null`.

Here is the relevant code with those changes applied:

```
var lS = localStorage.getItem("Logos"); // Removed JSON.parse()

if (lS !== null) { // Changed from `=== true` to `!== null`
  // Don't do anything
} else
  // Set item
}
```

Additionally, you are not doing anything in the first branch of the conditional statement (the `if` block of the `if/else`); to clean it up, you can simply invert the conditional, swap the branches, and remove the `else` branch:

```
if (lS === null) { // Changed from `!== null` to `=== null`
  // Set item
}
// `else` block removed
```

Another, optional, change: if you want, you can change the comparison to `null` to a falsiness check on `lS`: `if (lS === null)` to `if (!lS)`. *In this case*, the behavior will be the same (the other falsy values are `false`, `0`, `-0`, `0n`, `""`, `undefined`, and `NaN`).

All in all, the code comes to something like what I have put below.
I have also moved the creation of the picture src to inside the conditional so that a `Logo` is only created if needed, and stringified it immediately.

```
function populateStorage() {
    var lS = localStorage.getItem("Logos");
    
    if (!lS) {
        var pictureSrc = JSON.stringify([
          new Logo({ "picSrcl": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTMzIiBoZWlna........48L3N2Zz4K" })
        ]);

        localStorage.setItem("Logos", pictureSrc);
    }
}
```

**Note**
Loading the item from `localStorage` will *not* create an instance of `Logo`: JSON cannot store that sort of thing.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly when, and only when, the Logos variable already exits in localStorage , but it fails when it is not present. Maybe I should edit my question to let clear that first of all I need to set that variable to localStorage when I first load the page, and then, in subsecuents loads check if the variable is present to avoid replacing it. The stuff is that somewhere else in the page new objects are added to the variable and those must be kept.

Comment: Could you expand on how the solution I gave fails? I might have missed something.

Comment: It works, but only when the variable already exists in localStorage. Look at this, the first time I run the page it should set the variable to localStorage, then the next runs should avoid to replace it because it will be modified somewhere else and those changes must be kept.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify the situation

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not seeing how it fails. If the item is not present in `localStorage`, it writes the default. If it is present, it does nothing.

Comment: May I contact you to any email or Telegram profile to send screenshots of my console?

Comment: Why not include them in your question? Others have suggested basically the same approach as me, so it's probably relevant to everyone here.

Comment: I've tried it as best I can on my phone, and it seems to work fine. Have you tried using a web server instead of just opening the file?

Comment: It's not meant to be used on a web server as it is an hybrid app which will be compiled to different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

When you parse back the value you stored in LocalStorage (the value of variable pictureSrc, which is an array containing one object) it will not be strictly equal to true - it is not a boolean.

Replace the `lS === true` with just `lS`.

Comment: All right, done, but what should I place here '// here is where I am failing not to overwrite Logos variable', or just leave it blank?

Comment: All I want is to check if the variable exists or not, its content is irrelevant. Then, if it exists leave it alone, if not, set it in localStorage. Just that. I know it's so simple but maybe because of that is why I can't see it.

Comment: I found a logic mistake in my code else than your answer. Now it works. ¿should I answer it too in order to help people who comes after or just edit my question?

Comment: Instead of `if/else`, you can use `if (!lS)`. Then simply write it in that block, nothing else needed.