# Load base64 string from localStorage and display it on a div

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage

Based on my previous question, [Check if a localStorage variable exists then set an else if function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75695995/check-if-a-localstorage-variable-exists-then-set-an-else-if-function), and after checking some similar questions on how to load a base64 image and display it on a div, I have arrived to this code:

**html:**

```
<img id="logoholder" src="" alt="Logo" class="logoclient"/>
```

**js:**

```
var logoDataImage = localStorage.getItem("f7Logos");
    logoImg = document.getElementById("logoholder");
    logoImg.src = logoDataImage;
```

Let's notice that the base64 string is stored like this `[{"picSrcl":"data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTMzIiBoZWlna........48L3N2Zz4K"}]` and it's stored within some other string like `"id":"eda5dc81-fd3c-4ce9-8d3f-4d8f8672b83f","hasPic":false,"picId":"2"`, so I know I have to iterate through the variable to grab just the value of `picSrcl` and then display it as the `img src`on the div. But I don't get the key on how to do it. My code gives me this result:

[image: inspector log for img tag]

as it is grabing the hole content of `localStorage`.
How could I acomplish the task to obtain `<img id="logoholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA.......uhowAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Logo" class="logoclient">`?

After combining some of the comment's suggestions with the given answer I came up to this code, which works almost perfect, as I really need to grab the last added image and `[0].picSrc`is forcing to load the image on first objet:

```
var logoDataImage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("f7Logos"));
logoImg = document.getElementById("logoholder");
logoImg.src = logoDataImage['0'].picSrc;
```

As the user added some other images:

[image: Console result]

I will always need to grab the image in the last object, in this case the signed with a blue arrow, but taking into account that users will add their own images, so it's needed to catch the last in line.

It was very esay indeed using `slice`.

```
var logoDataImage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("f7Logos"));
logoImg = document.getElementById("logoimg");
logoImg.src = logoDataImage.slice(-1)["0"].picSrc;
```

to get the last item on the `array`.

Comment: _"is stored like this"_ - that is an array containing objects, encoded as JSON. So you will need to first of all decode this into an array again - and then _find_ your desired image object in there, based on whatever your actual criterion for identifying it, is.

Comment: try do `logoImg.src = logoDataImage[0].picSrc`

Comment: You must first use `JSON.parse(value)` then you can access `[0].picSrc`. But i would maybe perhaps just store the base64 as string and not as an array with objects. if the image is large then it's mostly wasteful to parse such a large json blob that is mostly built up by one large base64 value

Comment: I upadated the question with new elements for better understandig

Comment: You could either go and research "how do I get the last item of a JavaScript array" - or draw your own conclusion from your debug output. You have three items in your array, and the `length` also property reports `3`. Now how could we access the item with _index_ `2` based on that now, hm ...?

Comment: Oh, yes, and when user adds another image I go and change 2 to 3, and to 4, 5, 6 and so on. Great suggestion!

Comment: You might want to join a code practice site to help with this kind of thing. Knowing how to deal with arrays, objects, etc. is generally very useful, and it's more designed to help with those base concepts than stackoverflow is.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the JSON, then read the `picSrcl` property from the first element of that array.

```js
logoImg.src = JSON.parse(logoDataImage)[0].picSrcl;
```